# Why mail.log is not logging to file?

Tags: postfix, email-server, php-fpm

my server yesterday started sending thousands of spam emails. I blocked it adding `default_transport=No transport` to the postfix main.cf. But now of course I can't send legit emails as well.

I have 10+ websites in my Centos Server, using Nginx. I went via FTP to see if there were new strange files or recently edited (checking the dates). I couldn't find anything suspicious.

I want to track the source of the script sending emails - they are being sent using the generic email address configured in the server.

In my php.ini I added:

```
mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log
```

And I created the file `phpmail.log` via `touch` on `/var/log/` and I restarted the server using the command `systemctl restart php-fpm`

The file `phpmail.log` is not populating, still 0KB. Now it has the following righs:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache       0 Aug 10 12:47 phpmail.log
```

But I tried to give him nginx.nginx, root, root, web.web, but nothing seems to work. (of course after each chmod change I restarted once again php-fpm, and tried to send emails using for example the mail() contact form on my website).

And I tried also to make this file populate before adding `default_transport=No transport` to main.cf.

Not sure if it's useful for you, but `mailq` is full of mails in the queue.

Do you have any idea what is wrong with the file `phpmail.log` and why it's not populating, and/or how to find the root cause that is preventing it to populate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log) for the `mail.log` option, that file only logs messages sent with php's `mail()` function.

If the attacker is directly connecting to your local SMTP service with `fsockopen` then anything they send won't be logged.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is there any way to capture everything that is being sent via SMTP and ad the same time track the script where it was originated from (the script that calls the SMTP)?

Comment: `ad the same time track the script where it was originated from (the script that calls the SMTP)`, no, not that I know of. `Is there any way to capture everything that is being sent via SMTP`, you can run an SMTP proxy on the machine to catch the email, or can setup rules with iptables to do it that way, but neither will give you any more information than what you're getting now.